# I want to know why the loop wont stop here

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to write a program that searches a nested directory and then returns a location of searched file.In order to nest the scan inside directories I called the function inside the function. I was successful in doing so as the program worked but when I wanted was to stop the searching when the first hit is done. The code is below. Can someone make me understand why he iteration won't stop.

```
search = sys.argv[2]

def find(loca,term):
        count = 1
        for file in os.listdir(loca):
            if (count > 1):
                break
            try:
                os.chdir(f'{loca}\{file}')
                newloca = loca + '\\' + file
                find(newloca,term)
            except NotADirectoryError:
                pass
            except PermissionError:
                pass

            if(file == term):
                print(file)
                print(f"found the {term} at")
                print(os.getcwd())
               count += 1


find("E:/",search)
```

Comment: Please share the output of this program.

Comment: When you stepped through your program using a debugger, what did you see? Was it anything unexpected?

Comment: the output of this program will be as I told upside. The program scans the entire E directory and returns the search term which is provided in the console. All I want to know is why wont the iteration stop. Or am I doing something wrong

Comment: No the program works fine. Only the loop is not stopping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using recursion, you need some way of signaling the parent when you find a hit.  You can use `return` for that.

```
def find(loca,term):
    count = 1
    for file in os.listdir(loca):
        if (count > 1):
            break
        try:
            os.chdir(f'{loca}\{file}')
            newloca = loca + '\\' + file
            if find(newloca,term):
                return 1
        except NotADirectoryError:
            pass
        except PermissionError:
            pass

        if(file == term):
            print(file)
            print(f"found the {term} at")
            print(os.getcwd())
            count += 1
            return 1
```

Comment: thnx your code works.. one more thing is this the efficient method to do this or there is something else more efficient